# UWP Binding Checkboxes in ListView

Tags: uwp, windows-10, mvvm-light, windows-10-universal

So I am trying to design a list view where each item has a checkbox which are bound to a bool property in MVVM Light. I have everything binding and working correctly but now I would like to add a "Select All" and "Select None" button".

**Listview**

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Campuses, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Campus">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind selected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{x:Bind Name}" x:Name="checkBox"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code**

```
private ObservableCollection<Campus> _campuses { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Campus> Campuses
{
    get
    {
        return _campuses;
    }
    set
    {
        _campuses = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Campuses");
    }
}
```

So the binding is working properly and checking the box yourself changes the value saved in the object. When I try to change those programatically though, the UI does not update, only the code behind.

**How I would like to do it**

```
public void SelectAll()
{
    foreach (var item in Campuses)
    {
        item.selected = true;
    }
    RaisePropertyChanged("Campuses");
}
```

**What currently works**

```
public void SelectNone()
{
    List<Campus> old = Campuses.ToList<Campus>();

    foreach (var item in old)
    {
        item.selected = false;
    }
    Campuses = new ObservableCollection<Campus>(old);
}
```

Is there a way to change all of the values in the `ObservableCollection` and have the values in the objects update in the ListView without having to completely reassign the `ObservableCollection` I am binding too?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware that `DataBinding` will only work if each bound element has the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implemented.

Meaning, if you are binding the checkbox to the `Selected` property of the `Campus` class, you'll also need to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `Campus` class itself.

When you then change the value of the Selected property it will automatically reflect this change in the UI.

**Solution with code**
I added the following to the campus class to resolve the problem:

```
private bool _selected = false;

public bool selected
{
    get
    {
        return _selected;
    }
    set
    {
        _selected = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("selected"));
        }

    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly! Have added code to solution.